# To Check for a particular format in textbox

Tags: c#

I have a combobox containing two items namely Hardlens and Softlens and if i choose hardlens my textbox should only support the following format i.e.[PH00000000] and if i choose softlens the format should be like [PHY00000000] and the '0's vary with other numbers..

For hardlens the textbox should allow 'p' followed by 'h' followed by 'nos' For softlens the textbox should allow 'p' followed by 'h' followed by 'y' followed by 'nos' and if anyone enters others format letter it shouldn't be entered ....

Please help me regarding this situation...

Comment: Did you already take look to Regex validation? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @aymeric yes i took a look at regex validation but i dont know how to get the exact result i needed..It is a little bit confusing...I am a beginner..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the procedure i guess, using Regex ,You can even control number of 0's by Regex yourself

```
   private void textBox1_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    bool FoundMatch = false;
    if(combobox1.text.contains("hardners"))
        {

            try {
                FoundMatch = Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.text, "\\APHY\\0+\\z");
            } catch (ArgumentException ex) {

                // Syntax error in the regular expression
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                FoundMatch = Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.text, "\\APH\\0+\\z");
            }
            catch (ArgumentException ex)
            {
                // Syntax error in the regular expression
            }
        }

   }
```